# gRPC with flatbuffers applicability on low resource platform and serial channel

Tags: grpc, flatbuffers

We've tried to evaluate gRPC with flatbuffers on an embedded linux system, the resulting executable is ~6 MB for a very basic example with protobuf. We are looking to strip off as much as possible to move to platforms with even less resources. Only a direct channel over a "secure" serial transport; USB CDC, direct UDP/TCP or similar is required.

Is there a way to achieve this with standard gRPC configuration?

Is a custom channel required for this setup? Implementing a custom channel seems rather complicated (very high cyclomatic complexity in the included channels, even the in-memory one)

Is there any other guidance or examples/implementations for a simple custom channel implementation?

Comment: likely >95% of that code size is gRPC (which may include Protobuf, even though strictly you don't need it when using FlatBuffers, but it may still depend on it in places).

Comment: thanks, I'm not at all concerned about the contribution from flatbuffers, we're already using that on very small embedded platforms, but I want to figure out if gRPC/flatbuffers is a viable combination when the high level gRPC channels (HTTP/2 etc) and protobuf are removed/reconfigured to use flatbuffers and a simple non-authenticated/direct channel.

Comment: Sorry, no idea about that..